# Create an ASP.NET Web API solution in Xamarin Studio for OS X

Tags: macos, mono, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, xamarin-studio

I cannot figure out how to create an ASP.NET Web Api solution in Xamarin Studio on OS X.

I have tried to create an ASP.NET MVC 3 solution and inherit from `ApiController` but the class cannot be found.

What steps to I need to take to create an ASP.NET Web Api solution in Xamarin Studio on OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried installing the [WebApi NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi)?

Comment: I have not. I will try when I get home. Thanks.

Comment: Be careful with version you use, the latest may not be supported in mono: http://stackoverflow.com/q/22219229/516748

Answer (score 0):

As Far As I know Web API is not part of MVC3, it was added in MVC4.