# Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler', in Mono / xsp4

Tags: asp.net-web-api, mono

I'm getting this error when trying to access Web API controller, accessing via 127.0.0.1/api/myController/1

> Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler'
>   from assembly 'System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=5.1.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
>
> Description: HTTP 500.Error processing request.
>
> Details: Non-web exception. Exception origin (name of application or
>   object): System.Web.Http.WebHost.

Why is this happening? I see that it exists in System.Web.Http.WebHost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error was due to the use of latest assemblies via NuGet. It turns out that, currently, Mono isn't completely compatible with WebAPI v5.1.

I replaced all my MVC libraries with a previous (v4.0) version and it all worked.

Comment: Could you explain a little about how to go about doing that? I can't figure out how to revert libraries to previous versions in Xamarin Studio.

Comment: It's been a while, I've moved on to other projects so please bear with me. If I remember correctly, I used NuGet. I uninstalled the latest version and searched for an earlier one.