# Getting a System.TypeLoadException when trying to access a controller method in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs

I am trying to create a Angular SPA application with ASP.NET.

When I run the server, it loads everything fine, my javascript, css and the first index page.

The problem arises when I attempt to use a `ApiController`.

Here is my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Mvc.Ajax;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web.Http;
using Angular2.DAL;
using Angular2.Models;

namespace Angular2.Controllers {
    public class HomeController : ApiController {

        private ItemServiceContext db = new ItemServiceContext();

        // GET: api/Home
        public IEnumerable<Item> Get()
        {
            IEnumerable<Item> currentUserToDos = db.Items;
            return currentUserToDos;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my angular service:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.factory('itemSvc', ['$http', function ($http) {
    return {
        getItems : function(){
            return $http.get('/api/Home');
        },
        getItem : function(id){
            return $http.get('/api/Home/' + id);
        },
        postItem : function(item){
            return $http.post('/api/Home/',item);
        },
        putItem : function(item){
            return $http.put('/api/Home/', item);
        },
        deleteItem : function(id){
            return $http({
                method: 'DELETE',
                url: '/api/Home/' + id
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

And here is my WebApiConfig:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;


namespace Angular2 {
    public class WebApiConfig {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
```

}
}

Now when I attempt to do a

```
itemSvc.getItems().success(function (result) {
            $scope.items = result;
            console.log(result);
        }).error(function (err) {
            $scope.error = err;
        })
```

In my controller that is loaded in the index page, I get this error:

[image]

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Might I have something wrong in my `web.config` file? I am doing this project with monodevelop 5.7 on Linux.
Will provide more info if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24210346/could-not-load-type-system-web-http-webhost-routing-httprouteexceptionhandler), looks like a framework bug, although the [bug tracker](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=19314) disputes that it's a bug and seems to say that the Web API binaries are not supported.

Comment: You could try cloning the Web API source and compiling it in Mono, but I've never used Mono so I have no idea how you'd go about doing that. I found [this article](http://blog.oxfordcc.co.uk/aspnet-web-api-on-linux-apache-with-mono/) which makes it look...not trivial.