# Downgrade Web API to run on Linux using MONO

Tags: c#, asp.net, linux, mono, asp.net-web-api

I have Restful Web API developed with MVC4 in C#.net 4.5. Now I need to deploy this Web API on Cent OS Sever using Mono.

I looked around on web found that I need to downgrade the version to 4.0 to run it using Mono on Linux Machine.

If Any one have tried this before OR have any Idea How to DO it then please help...!!!

Comment: I'm running into this issue as well. Visual studio automatically creates a WebAPI 5.2 project. I tried to remove WebAPI, and reinstall from Nuget `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi -Version 4.0.30506`, but I'm running into version mismatch issues. Have you solved your issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Could not load type 'System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler', in Mono / xsp4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219229/could-not-load-type-system-web-http-webhost-httpcontrollerhandler-in-mono-x)

Comment: I'm going to leave this open. The dup cited is a question on diagnosing the problem. The poster asked how to perform the downgrade, not diagnose the problem. The dup does not explain how to downgrade. (There may well be another dup on performing the downgrade).

Answer (score 0):

To downgrade, simply do the following,

1. In VS change your project target framework to .NET 4 instead of .NET 4.5 or 4.5.1.
2. Update all NuGet packages.
3. Close VS.
4. Go to your project folder and open packages.config.
5. Find those Microsoft.AspNet.* NuGet package and change their version from 5.1.2 to 4.0.30506.

Note that for NuGet package downgrade there are a few exceptions,

- Microsoft.AspNet.Razor needs to be changed to version 2.0.30506.
- Many others.

The trick is to go to http://nuget.org and search for each packages, and choose the version that was released on Thursday, May 30 2013.

Good luck.

Comment: WebAPI 5.2 is separate from .Net 4.5. WebAPI 5.2 is not supported by 3.2.8 in Ubuntu 14.04 repositories. The @OP would need to downgrade to WebAPI 4.0 (4.0.30506).

Answer (score 0):

Following on from Lex's answer, I started with a working project under mono/windows and this is the diff I got from the downgrade... hope it helps someone.

```
git diff
diff --git a/MonoApi.csproj b/MonoApi.csproj
index b6fc96f..93f670c 100644
--- a/MonoApi.csproj
+++ b/MonoApi.csproj
@@ -66,14 +66,14 @@
     <HintPath>packages\Newtonsoft.Json.6.0.4\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting">
-    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
+    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
   <Reference Include="System.Web.Http">
-    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
+    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost">
-    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.2\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
+    <HintPath>packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.4.0.30506\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
   </Reference>
   </ItemGroup>
   <ItemGroup>
diff --git a/Controllers/PersonController.cs b/Controllers/PersonController.cs
index a9c79f0..8a58974 100644
--- a/Controllers/PersonController.cs
+++ b/Controllers/PersonController.cs
@@ -25,7 +25,8 @@ namespace MonoApi.Controllers
    Person person = databasePlaceholder.Get(id);
    if (person == null)
    {
-       throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
+       // HttpStatusCode method not implemenent on mono https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/current/src/System.Web.Http/HttpResponseException.cs
+       throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.NotFound));
    }
    return person;
  }
```

So far I am still targeting dot net 4.5 except these packages so we will see how that goes.